# Writing permission on android filesystems

Tags: java, android, xml

I should generate a .pdf file inside the android data folder to use the Java code below, with the permissions enabled in the XML manifest file. But when I run the code I have the following exception. The application has different permissions within the manifest, It should all be configured correctly, I state that the application I'm testing on an old Android 4. How can I solve this? and what is it due to?
**Exception**: error: **java. I. FileNotFoundException**: /data/my.pdf:
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

**Code:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " />

    public static Boolean GeneratePDF(String base64) {
        Boolean ret = true;

        try {
       String direttorio=""+Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        final File dwldsPath = new File(direttorio + "/" + "my.pdf");
        byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64, 0);
        FileOutputStream os;
        os = new FileOutputStream(dwldsPath, false);
        os.write(pdfAsBytes);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("\n Errore Generazione File: "+ex);
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;

    }
```

Comment: If you are testing your application OS level 6.0(Marshmallow) and above then you need take runtime permission from user because you accessing dangerous storage permission.

Here you go for more details about runtime permission https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
String direttorio=""+Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

To:

```
String direttorio= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
final File dwldsPath = new File(direttorio + "/" + my.pdf");
```

Comment: The file is a base64 that must be saved on the local filesystem (internal)

Comment: I tried your code again but continue to generate the same exception

Answer (score 1):

you have to give Write permission at run time.

It can be achieved something as following...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

  private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 111;

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {            
        GeneratePDF("your String name");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestPermission();
  }

  private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
    } else {
       GeneratePDF("your String name");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Android 6.0 and above,
there could be 2 ways:

1 if you're making only for demo purpose you can manually give permission to app 
    by going in settings->apps->permissions. Then allow all permission which are 
    required.

2 you've to implement runtime permissions so that user can allow it runtime.

Comment: Is it possible to set them at runtime for all android versions?

Comment: before android 6.0 permissions were asked by the time of installation, and after Android 6.0 the model has been changed so if you're targeting Android 6.0 and above you'll able to set them runtime.