# Android : Open Official File Manager App

Tags: android

I was trying to open the official file manager app (com.sec.android.app.myfiles for Samsung), I use this code :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);// even this does not work
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

This code launch DropBox App in my Samsung Galaxy. I need a list of the packages names of the file manager of the famous devices like Samsung (com.sec.android.app.myfiles),Sony,LG,Huawei,Oppo,Xiaomi,Htc.. So I can launch the file manager by package name.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to give a write permission at runtime. And on the success of write permission call below method. please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439600/writing-permission-on-android-filesystems/51439867#51439867) for runtime permission.

```
private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 100;

/**
     * Implicit intent for opening files on the device.
     */
    private void openFileChooser() {

        final Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        fileIntent.setType("*/*");

        fileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Select a File to Upload"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);

    }
```

All the best.

Comment: I don't want file chooser, I don't want to add extra permissions, I need only to open the file manager directly from my launcher app.